# Как проверить существование секции в .ini файле с помощью configparser?

Tags: python, config

Как проверить существование секции (`[Example]`) в .ini файле?

Создать её, если не существует.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Создатели Python рекомендуют использовать [`EAFP` (Easier to Ask for Forgiveness than Permission) идиому](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-eafp).

Пример:

```
from configparser import DuplicateSectionError

conf = configparser.ConfigParser()
conf.read('test.ini')

try:
    conf.add_section("new_section_name")
except DuplicateSectionError:
    # такая секция уже существует
    pass
```

PS ту же технику можно использовать, чтобы проверить существует ли определенный ключ в секции - для этого следует использовать `DuplicateOptionError` exception.

Answer (score 3):

Проверить проще через метод [has_section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#configparser.ConfigParser.has_section), но с ограничением, что нельзя проверить 'DEFAULT' секцию, для нее всегда вернет False

```
conf.has_section('Example')  # bool
conf.has_section('DEFAULT')  # всегда False
```